# TinyMCE - Cannot [reload images into editor] Read Properties of Undefined (Reading Replace)

Tags: php, wordpress, tinymce, tinymce-6

I am creating a front end editor for a Wordpress page. Part of my editor involves using TinyMCE for the post content.

Whilst users can successfully insert images from a source URL using image plugin, and save the post without issue, *realoading and displaying that data in the editor cannot load the image*.

When populating the TinyMCE editor with the post content, images are not displayed. Their image source shows a blob URL but it does not get parsed.

When attempting to re-save the post with the missing images, the console logs:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'replace')
    at Object.decode (tinymce.min.js:9:29800)
    at tinymce.min.js:9:218568
    at tinymce.min.js:9:141213
    at $ (tinymce.min.js:9:3294)
    at tinymce.min.js:9:141187
    at fe (tinymce.min.js:9:4687)
    at n (tinymce.min.js:9:141141)
    at mp (tinymce.min.js:9:141241)
    at Object.parse (tinymce.min.js:9:195693)
    at tinymce.min.js:9:221003
```

Rather than using Jquery ajax to populate the post editor template, i'm simply using

```
$content = get_post_field('post_content', $post_id);
```

And then when displaying the data, I simply echo this data between the `<textarea>` tags.

After some research, I made some basic assumptions that rather than simply echoing the post content straight onto the page, I needed to use the TinyMCE api function `tinymce.activeEditor.setContent()`

However even after a simple ajax call to populate this. I am met with yet another console error, despite `alert(data)` successfully popping up the html for the editor.

```
tinymce.min.js:9 
        
       Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'parse')
    at tinymce.min.js:9:208969
    at tinymce.min.js:9:209091
    at M.map (tinymce.min.js:9:2228)
    at tinymce.min.js:9:208325
    at Object.setContent (tinymce.min.js:9:209154)
    at tinymce.min.js:9:221994
    at tinymce.min.js:9:222010
    at Object.map (tinymce.min.js:9:75405)
    at Uv (tinymce.min.js:9:221954)
    at ZN.setContent (tinymce.min.js:9:379655)
```

If anyone has any suggestions on how or where I am going wrong with regards to representing the images back in the editor after the user has posted some post data, I would be very grateful.

I am using TinyMCE 6, and this is my init

```
tinymce.init({
            selector: 'textarea',
            toolbar_mode: 'wrap',
            plugins: 'image, media',
            toolbar: 'undo redo | styleselect | bold italic | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | outdent indent | image media',
            tinycomments_mode: 'embedded',
            tinycomments_author: 'Author name',
            convert_urls:true,
            relative_urls:false,
            remove_script_host:false,           
        });
```

--EDIT--

After some investigation, the Autoptimize Lazyload is causing issues.

Answer (score 0):

I think, if the image is already in the db, then if you can't view it on

the editor, then it a parsing issue... when image is retrieved from database

maybe tinymce doesn't know how the handle image data(from the url)

it knows it's there but don't know what to do with it.

you want to write a image handler to do that.

[TinyMCE docs](https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/plugins/opensource/image/)